# How to use reference const object passed to a function as a parameter

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Pos is a struct with x and y & I want to access these componenets of currentPos. but I get the errors. I cant directly access currentPos.x and .y as compiler cant handle it as the allocation hasnt been done yet. so i picked a global variable. but thats not working either.
  Errors are at the bottom of the code segment

```
 bwi_gridworld::Pos current_pose; //global variable

 void setCurrentPose(const bwi_gridworld::Pos& currentPos) {
        current_pose = *currentPos;
}



  char myAgent::nextAction(const bwi_gridworld::Pos& currentPos) {
    //Grid grid;
    int ht =  10;
    int width = 10;;
    setCurrentPose(currentPos);
    switch(id){
        case 0: {
                    if(current_pose.x - 0 < 5)
                        return 'e';
                    else if(current_pose.y - ht  < 5)
                        return 's';
                    else if(fabs(current_pose.x - (width/2)) < 5) 
                        return 'w';
                    else if(fabs(current_pose.y - (ht/2)) < 5)
                        return  'n';
                    else {

                        return defaultGetMove();
                        }


            }break;
        case 1:{
                if(fabs(current_pose.y - ht) < 5)
                    return 'e';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.x -x) < 5) 
                    return 'w';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.x - x/2) < 5)
                    return 's';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.y - ht/2) < 5)
                    return 'n';
                else return defaultGetMove();

            }break;
        case 2:{
                if(current_pose.x - 0 < 5)
                        return 'e';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.x - ht/2) < 5) 
                        return 'w';
                else if( fabs(current_pose.y - 0) < 5) 
                    return 'n';
                else if( fabs(current_pose.y - (width/2)) < 5)
                    return 's';
                else
                    return defaultGetMove();
            }break;
        case 3:{

                if(fabs(current_pose.x - width) < 5) 
                    return 'w';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.x - (width/2)) < 5)
                    return 'e';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.y - ht/2) < 5)
                    return 's';
                else if(fabs(current_pose.y - 0) < 5)
                    return 'n';
                else
                    return defaultGetMove();
            }
        }
}





   /home/bonny/bwi_gridworld/agent/src/myAgent.cpp:7:20: error: aggregate ‘bwi_gridworld::Pos current_pose’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     bwi_gridworld::Pos current_pose;
                        ^
    /home/bonny/bwi_gridworld/agent/src/myAgent.cpp: In function ‘void setCurrentPose(const bwi_gridworld::Pos&)’:
    /home/bonny/bwi_gridworld/agent/src/myAgent.cpp:23:19: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const bwi_gridworld::Pos’)
        current_pose = *currentPos;
```

Comment: Just define the types of the members of `bwi_gridworld::Pos`!

Comment: If you get errors you should include them in the question. "not working either" is a bit too vague

Comment: And references aren't dereferenced with `*`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos could you please tell me how to define the types of the members

Comment: The error indicates that they are not defined yet. Figure out what they are  and add definition of them.

Comment: what is "bwi_gridworld" ? Is it a namespace ?

Comment: First error on "myAgent.cpp:7:20", could be because missing #include header file or you have just forward declarations.
Second error on "myAgent.cpp:23:19", because you have mistakenly put ‘operator*’. Just 'current_pose = currentPos' might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is what I did - one comment made me realize that you cant and dont need to dereference the reference using a * operator. You'd do something like that with a pointer not a reference.

My struct Pos had a constructor that was of the form Pos(intx,int y, int time) :
So I simply made current_pose an object of the struct using the statement

```
bwi_gridworld::Pos current_pose((currentPos).x, (currentPos).y,0);
```

and it worked. Long story short you dont and cant dereference a reference (unlike a pointer) using *